# Не работает вставка стрима от видеосервер Shinobi на сайт через <iframe>

Tags: streaming

Имеется IP видеокамера сконфигурированная в Shinobi видеосервере.
Видеосервер выдает многопользовательский стрим по URL [http://217.114.155.238/qno7iHEIAt7rgH36FhHJs6zvtIkQk6/embed/mX6OYC1vkZ/ZdmuJDZwFF/jquery|fullscreen|gui](http://217.114.155.238/qno7iHEIAt7rgH36FhHJs6zvtIkQk6/embed/mX6OYC1vkZ/ZdmuJDZwFF/jquery%7Cfullscreen%7Cgui)
Если вставить его в адресную строку браузера то Вы его увидите.

Однако, когда пытаешься встроить в вебстраницу сайта через `<iframe>` как указано в API docs

```
<iframe src="http://217.114.155.238/qno7iHEIAt7rgH36FhHJs6zvtIkQk6/embed/mX6OYC1vkZ/1kk5A6pmJm8999/jquery|fullscreen|gui"></iframe>
```

https://www.cams-online.ru/izhevsk/allcats/28/

то данный html подгружает пустую страницу: `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`
Выглядит так словно указанный УРЛ не верен и страница не загрузилась, но мы же видели, что он есть и рабочий.

Как исправить данную проблему?

П.С. Видеосервер стоит дома за роутером Микротик, я уже подумываю, что может что-то не верно настроено в НАТ и не открыты какие-то порты на видеосервере?

Answer (score 1):

Видимо все дело в том, что браузеры блокирую смешанный трафик. Основной сайт работает по https, а видео эмбедится с сервера, который на http. Считается, что это не безопасно.

Решение: установка на видеосервер Shinobi бесплатного SSL сертификата, например, с
[Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/)

Comment: Дополню ваш ответ. Достаточно открыть консоль браузера и увидеть ошибку **Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.cams-online.ru/izhevsk/allcats/28/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure frame 'http://217.114.155.238/qno7iHEIAt7rgH36FhHJs6zvtIkQk6/embed/mX6OYC1vkZ/ZdmuJDZwFF/jquery%7Cfullscreen%7Cgui'. This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
tag.js:1**